subjunctive - present tense - after taste (verb)

There is a new patty on the market. Its main ingredient is insects. Producers say that it taste like peanuts.

A typical correction here might be: "it tastes like" (it = the patty).
... say that it would taste like = say it taste like.
So, is "taste" - as a present tense subjunctive - acceptable, rare, wrong?

Another typical correction here might be it's = it is. The Saxon genitive its = of it has no apostrophe. I've no idea why you think taste might be "present tense subjunctive" in your example context. It's just wrong.

It's wrong, and also its [main ingredient...] does not have an apostrophe.

@MichaelHarvey: Snap!

@FumbleFingers - you beat me by 8 secs!

Ah, but don't I get extra brownie points for writing more words? Or should I get less points, on account of they add nothing of value?

@FumbleFingers - more. I'm feeling generous because of you-know-what.

Also - its main ingredient is insects.

"The producers say that it would taste like peanuts" is only a valid sentence if the patty doesn't yet exist, but the makers can predict (perhaps from experimental versions) how it would taste if they were to manufacture it.

@NederlanditisNederlanditis You've proposed something completely nonstandard without explaining why you think it's acceptable. This question has a vanishingly small chance of being useful to anyone, including you, since we can't address your underlying misconception if we don't know what it is. You can edit the question if you don't think it should be closed.

@Kate. This appears to be helpful.

What a rare tone! English for learners?! My question is not even useful for me? Who are you?

Let me try that in a different tone. No, this usage won't do. But if you can explain why you thought it might, then we can give a more useful answer than "no." (Meanwhile @the-baby-is-you this question does appear to me to be on-topic and good enough to answer, even if edits could bring better answers. It is emphatically not a proofreading question (I wonder who keeps misusing that reason?), and not easily answerable by a reference work.

@Andy Bonner. As much as the conjunctive mood (in German Konjunktiv) is the same as the subjunctive, there appears to be a distinct difference in its usage/ application. The matter might get tricky rather quickly because in English there is this limited number of verb forms. Let's leave it there. Or: My error seems to be coming from an ill-placed idea about similarities in grammar. After all, I got my answer.

First: Yes, the original quote needs correction. In "producers say that it taste like peanuts," we have a singular subject and plural verb.
Yes, using the singular form "tastes" would be a common correction, as it stays the closest to the apparent intended meaning.

... say that it would taste like = say it taste like.

These two aren't the same. When we add "would," we get a hypothetical. It sounds like you've been taught to call this "subjunctive"; I don't want to undo too much of your teaching, but I used the word "hypothetical" instead because the subjunctive mood is a tricky subject and English doesn't really have a special verb tense for it. But this usage needs the helping verb "would." Many usages have helping verbs, and their "help" is not optional! So if you take the "would" away again, then you are back to plain old simple present, and must use "tastes."
Now, is the hypothetical a good choice here?

There is a new patty on the market. Its main ingredient is insects. Producers say that it would taste like peanuts.

It's not terrible, and not necessarily something that you would insist on "correcting," but it's not the most logical choice. The new patty already exists! It's on the market! It has a taste. Its taste isn't imaginary or potential. The hypothetical usage would make more sense if producers were still planning and perfecting the patty.
